# How to access HANA VIEW from SAP VORA

Tags: vora

I am trying to access Hana VIEW from SAP VORA using zeppelin but getting an error "No schema provided for non-existing table!".
I can't find any information about it. If anyone knows anything regarding that, that would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Querying views in HANA via the HANA datasource is supported. The `path`-option takes either a table name or a view name. I just tested it and it works for me both on the Spark-shell and in Zeppelin (with both Vora1.0 and Vora1.1). Are your view name in Vora and HANA identical?

Here the Zeppelin code I used. 'TESTVIEW' is a view in my HANA system.

```
%vora
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sparktestview
USING com.sap.spark.hana
OPTIONS (
  path         "TESTVIEW",
  host         "myhost",
  dbschema     "SPARKTEST",
  user         "myuser",
  passwd       "mypwd",
  instance     "00"
)  

%vora 
select * from sparktestview
```

Comment: I still have same issue, can any one tried to access HANA Calculation Views using VORA ?

Comment: The same works with CalcViews, e.g. to access calcView 'VORATESTVIEW' in package 'voratest' you need to set 'path' to          "voratest/VORATESTVIEW". Make sure to use dbschema  "_SYS_BIC" (this is where the active CalcViews are located). To make sure you use the right schema name + view name, you can run a simple query in HANA Studio, e.g. SELECT top 1 * FROM "_SYS_BIC"."voratest/VORATESTVIEW"

Comment: Thanks F.Legler !!  It worked for me as well .I have not used correct schema name earlier .